# I need to remove a donate image which works like button and lands a user to official paypal payment website

Tags: html, api, bootstrap-4, paypal

Paypal has an option to generate donate button if u go to this link [generate donation button by entering data asked by paypal](https://www.paypal.com/donate/buttons)

the image used by paypal is ugly and becomes blur when zoomed so I decided to change the the image but when I tried changing the image to actual button using tags the link did not work. I also tried changing type=image to type=button still my problem was not resolved. this is how it looks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X42rO.png)
the html code is

```
<div class="donate">  
                        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/donate" method="post" target="_top">
                          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="prabcrist@gmail.com" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Server cost and keeping site live" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif"  name="submit" title="safer way to apy online" alt="Donate with PayPal button" />
                        </form>
                      </div>
```

the html I used

```
 <div class="donate">  
                        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/donate" method="post" target="_top">
                          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="prabcrist@gmail.com" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Server cost and keeping site live" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                          <input type="button" value="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif"  name="submit" title="safer way to apy online" alt="Donate with PayPal button" />
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the image 'src' attribute if you want it to be a regular, non-image button. However, it won't look very good unless your page has CSS styling.

Maybe [find a different image](https://www.google.com/search?q=paypal%20donate%20button&tbm=isch) you like better.